# Отправка на конкретное место в скрипте при нажатии в редакторе Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

В редакторе Unity есть удобные Debug.Log логи. Помимо того что они выводят сообщение в консоль, при клике на это сообщение тебя перенаправляет прямо в нужное место в скрипте - место, откуда был вызван этот дебаг.
Но если хочется как то обернуть этот метод и добавить туда время события, например так

```
public static void LogError(this object obj, string message)
{     
        message += DateTime.Now.ToString();
        Debug.LogError(message);
}
```

То любой клик по такому дебагу в консоли перенаправляет нас на этот самый метод, на нашу "Обертку". Как сделать так, чтобы можно было дополнять метод Debug.Log и при этом сохранялась функциональность перенаправления на нужную строчку скрипта?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть пара решений для вашего вопроса:

1. Использовать ассет Console Enhanced (free/pro)
2. Написать своё собственное окно консоли.

Ну с первым вариантом всё понятно, но если вы хотите для себя, как уважающий себя программист, создать своё окно с блек джеком и плюшками.

Приведу пример реализации:

```
 public static void Log(object obj, string msg) {
    // берёт стактрейс вызова
    string stackTrace = UnityEngine.StackTraceUtility.ExtractStackTrace();

    // разделяем стактрейс на строки. символ '\n' олицетворяет переход на новую строку
    string[] row = stackTrace.Split('\n'); // метод Split('символ') разделяет строку на массив строк

    // берем трейс который вызвал данный метод Log. 
    // данное число "1" можно менять, в зависимости какой хотите скрипт выбрать их стактрейса
    // если полноценное консольное окно  делать, то тут уже через цикл пускать
    string trace = row[1]; //строка будет выглядеть так: "tester:ShowWarning() (at Assets\Scripts\tester.cs:26)"

    // далее попытаемся взять конкретный скрипт и открыть в редакторе скриптов
    // отрезаем всё лишнее, используя пробел между символами
    string filePathAndLine = trace.Split(' ')[2]; // строка будет выглядеть так: "Assets\Scripts\tester.cs:26)"

    // избавляемся от двоеточия
    string filePath = filePathAndLine.Split(':')[0];// строка будет выглядеть так: "Assets\Scripts\tester.cs"

    //  попутно записываем номер строки
    string lineString = filePathAndLine.Split(':')[1]; // строка будет выглядеть так: "26)" // затем необходимо удалить скобку

    // удаляем скобку. Можно было использовать Remove, но это всё зависит от вашего усмотрения
    string line = lineString.Split(')')[0];

    // парсим строку в число
    int lineNumber = int.Parse(line); 

    //загружаем объект чтобы потом его использовать
    UnityEngine.Object file = UnityEditor.AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<Object>(filePath);

    // берём в фокус скрипт (словно кликнули на него мышкой)
    UnityEditor.Selection.activeObject = file; // не обязательно

    // подсвечиваем объект желтым 
    UnityEditor.EditorGUIUtility.PingObject(file);// не обязательно

    // открываем скрипт в редакторе скриптов на определённом номере строки
    UnityEditor.AssetDatabase.OpenAsset(file, lineNumber);

}
```

Надеюсь вам поможет данный ответ, Удачи!